# Align Multiple Views at the bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm new to `Android` and I want to create an activity with 3 set (line) of `Buttons` at the bottom of screen .For my example I wrote this code for 2 set (line) of buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="5" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="10" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

I want to buttons 6-10 put on (above) the buttons 1-5 (like Stack).

How I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: How does it look now? Overlapping?

Comment: Yes buttons 6-10 overlap 1-5. buttons 1-5 have not been shown

Comment: I have answered your question if that is what you want!

Comment: Feel free to comment below my answer if my descriptions are unclear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `RelativeLayout` with two `LinearLayout`s.

You should give both your `LinearLayout` `id`s and after that you will position the other `LinearLayout` which you want to be on top by giving it the atrribute

```
android:layout_above="@id/the_id_of_the_one_you_want_to_be_below"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your two LinearLayout in **a parent linearLayout**.
That parent layout need to be aligned to the bottom.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

      <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

      <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />

      <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />

      <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4" />

      <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="5" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

      <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6" />

      <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7" />

      <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8" />

      <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="9" />

      <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="10" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```